# put decimal after 2 place on key down event from right to left

Tags: jquery, input, decimal

I need number in this order from right to left when user enters a number

00.01

00.12

01.23

12.34

like initially "00." should be there .
Most of the solution are restricting value from 2 places or converting to decimal after focus out event

I tried this code but not able to get logic correct

http://jsfiddle.net/BB7pS/310/

```
$(document).ready( function(e){

    $('#input').keydown( function(e){

        var s1=$(this).val();

    if (s1.length <2) 
    {
    s1 = '0.0' + s1;
      $(this).val(s1);
      e.preventdefault();
    }

   if (s1.length < 5) 
    {
    s1='';
    s1=$(this).val().slice(3);
    s1 = '0.' + s1;
      $(this).val(s1);
    }

    });
});
```

I need to some suggestion how it can be achieved . thanks

Comment: *Any* code that uses `$(this).val(` during change/keyup/input events will be a nightmare for users that actually know what they're doing.  You need to preserve the input caret and allow for undo (cntrl-z).  Using an `<input>` tag will never give you what you want in a nice user-friendly manner.   The work-around is to use `<div>` and handle everything an `<input>` does - which is no small amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below logic to replace characters and decimal on `keyup` event

```
$(document).ready( function(e){
    $('#input').keyup( function(e){

        var s1=$(this).val();
    if(s1){
       s1 = s1.replace(".","");
       s1 = "000" + s1; // append zeros so that 00.0X can be achieved
       var position = s1.length - 2; //calculate decimal position which is before last 2 digits
       var output = [s1.slice(0, position), ".", s1.slice(position)].join(''); // create string with decimal
       console.log(output);
      $(this).val(parseFloat(output).toFixed(2)); // push the value to input
    } else {
      $(this).val("00.00");
    }

    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB7pS/327/)

Comment: Try to use Shift + Arrow keys to select a part of an already set input, so you can type something else. For example, set `2.15` and try to select the `.15` part clicking after the dot and pressing Shift + Right arrow. The only good answer (UI wise) is: *"never touch user input; store it so you can rely on it"*. Besides, scripts such as the above fail miserably on touch devices, on iOS devices and on Android devices, which provide a completely different UI for handling inputs, specific to each of those devices. It's a big no-no.

Comment: The first major flaw with this approach is: you should not change the input value on `keyup`. You could display what current input will be parsed into in a different element, to inform the user, which will enable them to work on current input value so it results into whatever they want to input. But do not change the input value. Just display what you're going to parse it into.

Comment: yes , logic is what i want . However i achieved this with keydown event . i accept this as answer. thanks

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: I got a bug in this solution . I tried to enter value "50.00" , but it is not letting me accept zeros. please suggest

Comment: i have added `toFixed` to fix the bug. try updated solution

Comment: happy to help you, you can accept this answer if you find it useful

Comment: one more small issue I am facing . if i place cursor on textbox with existing decimal value . it is should focus to extreme right .Can you help me with that ?

Comment: I think you should post a new question on SO as you are amending your requirement as and when solution provided